# how it works this currency converter api, get rate?

Tags: php, fixer.io

I'm trying to use [this api (currency exchange api)](https://cc.hirak.cc/usd_hkd). This returns something like this:

```
{
  "from":"USD",
  "to":"HKD",
  "rate":7.7950999999999996958877090946771204471588134765625
}
```

I send the request with `file_get_contents()` and this seems to work.
 My problem is that I can't access the array key `rate`.

```
$r = file_get_contents('https://cc.hirak.cc/usd_hkd');
print_r($r['rate']); // nothing is shown. This is the problem.
print_r($r);  // result shows ( all the array )
```

How can I access just the `rate` key?

Comment: I haven't written PHP code in a while, but are you sure `file_get_contents takes the `Content-Type` header into account and return an array? Maybe a type checking on `$r` would help. If it's a simple string it's quite clear what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing an string instead of array,
Try this code, I think this will work:

```
$r = json_encode(file_get_contents('https://cc.hirak.cc/usd_hkd'),true);
```